# Telegram bot перестал писать в группу

Tags: python, aiogram

Подскажите в чем проблема. Бот добавлен в группу, выданы права админа. В коде, когда выполняется условие, он должен отписать сообщение в группу. При запуске бота, отправка работает, потом работает еще дня 2-3 и перестает отправлять сообщения в группу. Ошибок не выдает. Отправка обычным методом `bot.send_message('id группы','текст')`.

```
async def load_comments(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    data_res = await sqlite_db.read_date(message.from_user.id)
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        if data_res == str(data_data): 
            await bot.send_message('-1001638687094','Оформлен пропуск на текущую дату.')
```

Comment: а сам то код где?

Comment: @DaLadno добавил код

Comment: @DaLadno Прошу прощения, не до конца освоил форматирование тут. В самом коде правильное форматирование, именно тут на сайте ошибся

Comment: Бот у вас на сервере? если бесплатные или тестовые сервера то они медленно работают. Если у вас бот работает 2-3 дня значит дело не в коде.

Comment: Я поэтому и поправляю, что бы людей не путать

Comment: @UmarEgamberdiev Бот пока работает с компьютера. Может ли в этом быть проблема?